# fwidth() tegra 3 glsl

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, tegra

[image]

This is result of this program rendering few quads on Tegra 3 device :

```
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
precision mediump float;

                                                                
uniform sampler2D sampler2d;                                                                            
varying vec2 textureCoord;          

void main() 
{                                                                                           

    vec4 texColor = texture2D(sampler2d,textureCoord);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(fwidth(texColor.a),0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

Texture i am using is an empty, transparent png, but there is no matter what i put in this texture those wireframes are always visible.

Same code on Mali-400 device works ok.
Can anybody tell me is Tegra fwidth implementation proper or there is something wrong with my code?
Code above is only a example, showing only error part of shader.

Comment: Different devices are allowed to do derivatives differently to each other, so don't expect things to look exactly the same from GPU to GPU. Have you tried `glHint`ing with `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_DERIVATIVE_HINT`? Also, what are the sampling parameters for that texture? This wouldn't explain the lines on the insides of the quads, but using `GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER` would cause interpolation with the border color. `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` should fix that.

Comment: there is only mipmap hint available in es 2.0

Comment: OK, there is GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_DERIVATIVE_HINT_OES, but it isnt the cause of problem

Comment: Might as well report a bug to the driver maintainers then. I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a very similar problem, with triangle wire frame artifacts showing over our fonts after anti-aliasing was applied, only on Tegra 3 devices. I narrowed down the issue to be with the result returned from the fwidth() function. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the root of the issue (I'm expecting it's something to do with the derivative being incorrectly large at triangle edges?).

However, I did find a work around. I used colour changes to determine that the artifacts showed up when the width returned by fwidth was greater than .2. I then ignored values greater than .2 and replaced them with a more reasonable hardcoded fwidth value - you may need to do some fiddling to find one that works for your use case, for me 0.025 was sufficient.

To avoid if branching in my shader code, I used a combination of mix and step to replace the fwidth value when needed:

```
mediump float dist = texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut).a;
mediump float width = fwidth(dist);
width = mix(width, 0.025, step(0.2, width)); // if (width > 0.2) width = 0.025
```

While far from ideal, using this width instead of the raw fwidth when applying smoothstep anti-aliasing allowed me to display my text with no artifacts.